# Cannot Access PHPMyAdmin on Windows LAMP Stack

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cookies, phpmyadmin

I installed LAMP on my linux laptop one month ago and it was still working fine. But then recently I can't access phpmyadmin. It always pops up this error:

> Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

I tried clearing the cache and cookies of my Mozilla browser but it still won't work. By the way, I'm new to Linux so I'm having a hard time configuring what might went wrong.

Comment: Look at the session folder (which can be found through the output of `phpinfo();`); check that the drive has free space and that the folder has proper permissions for the webserver or PHP process to read and write files. Note that this is on the webserver itself, not cookies on your local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving Read Write permission to the folder

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/php/session/
```

Comment: it says: chmod cannot access '/var/lib/php/session/': No such file or directory

Comment: Ok folder may be in a different path check your php.ini for your session path ... session.save_path

Comment: it says here, it's on /opt/lampp/temp

Comment: then change location 
sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/temp/